# Export excel and pdf in different directory

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I was teaching myself for kendo grid and could not find example or demo for exporting pdf and excel to different directory other then download folder.
Currently my code automatically download exported files to "download" folder when I press the button for "export to excel" and "export to pdf"

I've tried "saveAs()" but this was not the function that I was looking for. Here is my code.

```
                toolbar: ["create", "excel", "pdf"],
                excel: {
                    fileName: "Kendo UI Grid Export.xlsx",
                    filterable: true
                },
                pdf: {
                    allPages: true,
                    avoidLinks: true,
                    paperSize: "A4",
                    margin: { top: "2cm", left: "1cm", right: "1cm", bottom: "1cm" },
                    landscape: true,
                    repeatHeaders: true,
                    template: $("#page-template").html(),
                    scale: 0.8
                },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For security reasons, you can't access local folders. So it´s not possible to target your export local folder.
Kendo has also interesting features, considering that you are learning, features for saving files (server-side). [Here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/saving-files)

Here is one example

```
var dataURI = "data:text/plain;base64,SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh";
kendo.saveAs({
    dataURI: dataURI,
    fileName: "test.txt",
    proxyURL: "/path/to/proxy",
    forceProxy: true
});
```

Comment: so basically there is no way to save in different local directory due to security reason in Kendo UI?

Comment: No, there is no way of controlling if from your webapp @pdn